# Why does SVG path collapse to 0x0 when built using DOM interface, but works when building using jQuery string

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, svg

I am trying to create a checkbox that uses a svg as the check mark. I wanted to build the svg through the DOM interface, but when built as such, the path would become 0x0 and the checkmark would therefore not display.

Initially I was building the svg as:

```
let checkboxSvgEl: SVGSVGElement = 
    document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')

checkboxSvgEl.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
checkboxSvgEl.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 12 10')
checkboxSvgEl.setAttribute('fill', 'none')

checkboxSvgEl.classList.add('ml-checkbox__check-icon')

let svgPathEl: SVGPathElement = 
    document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path')

svgPathEl.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'd', 'M10.32.5L12 2.086 4.164 9.5 0 5.562l1.68-1.586 2.484 2.34L10.32.5z')

svgPathEl.setAttribute('fill', '#ffffff')

checkboxSvgEl.append(svgPathEl)
this.checkboxDiv.append(checkboxSvgEl)
```

This did not work, however when the svg is created as

```
let svg = $('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 10" fill="none" class="ml-checkbox__check-icon"><path d="M10.32.5L12 2.086 4.164 9.5 0 5.562l1.68-1.586 2.484 2.34L10.32.5z" fill="#ffffff"></path></svg>')

$(this.checkboxDiv).append(svg)
```

it works.

Am I incorrectly using the SVGSVGElement and/or SVGPathElement interfaces?

Potentially it has to due with the display of the parent. It is wrapped in a div that is displayed as inline-flex, however changing that value to block in dev console did not fix the issue.

Comment: Use `svgPathEl.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M10.32.5...')`instead of `svgPathEl.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'd', 'M10.32.5...')` Also I would use setAttributeNS for `viewBox` and `fill`

Comment: @enxaneta beat me to it, but indeed, it will work fine with `null` as the namespace in `setAttributeNS`: https://jsfiddle.net/g5c7dxa2/

Comment: You don't need to use `setAttributeNS()`. Using `setAttribute(name, value)` works just fine.  You only need to use `setAttributeNS()` for attributes with a namespace. For example `xlink:href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments were correct:

Using setAttributeNS passing in null as the first parameter fixed the issue. Also using the same approach when creating viewBox and fill attributes.

Edited code:

```
let checkboxSvgEl: SVGSVGElement document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')

checkboxSvgEl.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
checkboxSvgEl.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', '0 0 12 10')
checkboxSvgEl.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none')

checkboxSvgEl.classList.add('ml-checkbox__check-icon')

let svgPathEl: SVGPathElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path')

svgPathEl.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M10.32.5L12 2.086 4.164 9.5 0 5.562l1.68-1.586 2.484 2.34L10.32.5z')           
svgPathEl.setAttribute('fill', '#ffffff')

checkboxSvgEl.append(svgPathEl)
this.checkboxDiv.append(checkboxSvgEl)
```

The last comment was also correct. I removed setAttributeNS from viewBox, fill and path attributes and the check mark functioned. It seems that the main issue was setting the attribute namespace to a value other than null.

Many thanks!